# Converting characters in a variable to their original ascii form

Tags: python

Okay, so I've been doing a lot of research and I couldn't find any answers so I came here to ask for some help.

My problem that I have encountered is I am having trouble taking a variable, then in the background of my code converting each individual string of that variable back to its ascii form and manipulating it using math, such as +, -, * and /. Here is my code..

**Note:** I had one theory, which is using a for loop to say for each character in this variable, do... blah blah. Here's my code anyways.

```
import random
import sys
import time


invalid_input = True

def start():

print("Welcome to the Encryption / Decryption Program!")
menuAnswer = input("Please select the number corresponding to the option you would like (1 - 3)\n---------------------------------\n[1] Encrypt\n[2] Decrypt\n[3] Exit the program\n---------------------------------\n")

if menuAnswer == '1':
    print("You have chosen to Encrypt!")
    invalid_input = False
    message = open("sample.txt","r")
    msgName = input("What is the name of the text document you would like to Encrypt?\n")
    msgName = msgName.upper()
    if msgName == 'SAMPLE':
        key = '' #This variable will have the encryption key stored inside of it.

        for i in range(0,8):
            random_number = (random.randint(33,162)) #Generate a random ascii number from the range 33 to 162
            key +=str(chr(random_number)) #Convert and store this ascii number as a character to the variable 'Key'
        print(key)
        print("Remember this key, as you will need it to decrypt your file!")
        #\\ Offset //# #Finding the offset, must be able to convert each individual character of the key variable and return it to its usual form to manipulate using math.
    else:
        print("Invalid Filename")



elif menuAnswer == '2':
    print("You have chosen to Decrypt!")
    invalid_input = False
elif menuAnswer == '3':
    print("You have chosen to exit!")
    invalid_input = False
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Exiting...")
    time.sleep(1.5)
    exit()
else:
    print("Invalid Input, Please try again!")

while invalid_input:
        start()
```

Sorry if this question was difficult to understand, I am really confused myself and have been stuck on this for a week straight.

Comment: You're not reading the file that you opened.

Comment: No I have read the file - this is not the error. I am trying to convert each character individually in the key variable and manipulate it in the background of the code.

Comment: Go with your theory and loop through each character individually and convert it to a number using `ord()`. `for c in s: ord(c)`

Comment: I can't see what your question is here. All this code does is generate an eight-character random string. What problem are you having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to convert each character of your string to its ascii number and then do some sort of math operation on it and then convert it back to a string which you can do using `ord()` like so

```
s = 'Sample'
tmp = ''
for i in s:
    tmp += chr(ord(i)+1)
print tmp

Tbnqmf
```

Although with the code you have you don't need to convert it to a string and then back to characters to manipulate it you can just manipulate it as soon as you pick a random number like so

```
import random

def start():
    key = '' 
    for i in range(0,8):
        random_number = (random.randint(33,162)) 
        key +=chr(random_number+1) 
        print(key)

start()
```

**Note** you need to be careful when manipulating your characters since you could manipulate it to a number that is not an ascii character

Comment: Thank you! This was just what I needed!